# Intuition behind this inverse image notation on measure theory.

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-calculus

So my professor for measure theory when talking about $\sigma$-algebras says statements like:

$$ \{f \in \tilde{E}\} \in \mathcal{F}  $$

when he wants to denote $f^{-1}(\tilde{E}) \in \mathcal{F}$.

Is this a commonly accepted notation in measure theory/stochastics? If it is, what is the intuition behind this notation? I don't at all see how saying $f \in \tilde{E}$ conjures notions of inverse images. If anything to me it seems like notation for an actual image.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Maybe just pretend they forgot to write $\{x\mid f(x) \in \tilde E\}$. Like, they were too "lazy" to write the whole thing.

Comment: AHH! So that's where the notation must have come from! Thanks, that was either some creative thinking on your part or a dumb oversight from me.

Comment: Think of this abomination as the dual of the tendency to, when $x$ and $y$ are related variables, write abominations like $y = y(x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, you can think of $\{ f \in \tilde E \}$ as a shorthand version of $\{ x \mid f(x) \in \tilde E \}$.